# PhoneGap: Play sound using Android's Alarm Volume

Tags: android, cordova, audio

I'm currently using a Media object to play a sound in a PhoneGap app. However, it uses the "Music & Videos" volume. Is there a way to get it to play using the "Alarm" volume?

Answer (score 1):

Are you use `AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM`?

I think you use `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`.

You can see [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html).